# Where to download SISCO-simulator for integrated supply chain operations

Tags: simulation, supply-chain

I am trying to find the software called SISCO (Simulator For Integrated Supply Chain Operations). It is developed by [Chatfield et al. (2006)](https://pennstate.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/sisco-an-object-oriented-supply-chain-simulation-system)<sup>1</sup>. However, it seemed that the authors did not include the link to the software. Can anyone tell me the place to find SISCO?

---

<sub>Reference</sub>

<sub>[1] Chatfield, D. C., Harrison, T. P., & Hayya, J. C. (2006). SISCO: an object-oriented supply chain simulation tool utilizing JAVA and XML. *Decision Support Systems.*</sub>

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors?

Comment: I emailed the first author, but no reply yet. I'll update this question if the author replies.

Comment: @Jayz, If you would like to use a free simulation software with a focus on the supply chain, [Jaamsim](https://jaamsim.com/index.html) is a useful one. :)

Comment: @A.Omidi Thank you very much! I am gonna try to see if this software will work for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of this software replied to my inquiry, but unfortunately, the author said he didn't make it freely available. It is a bit old and was developed on Windows XP. It is likely not going to run on Windows 10 or higher now.

Comment: Seems like the question is answered, so feel free to accept your own answer.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610, It is so cool! Dr. Snyder. :)